# How is int[] []x[] a legal array declaration in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

```
int[] []x[];
```

I know that

```
int[] x;
int x[];
int []x;
```

and similar declares an array perfectly fine, but how does 3 sets for brackets, work exactly?

Comment: My uneducated guess would be declaring an array of two dimensional arrays of ints.

Comment: No one should write such unreadable code.  I'd say int x[][][]; would be least surprising.

Comment: @duffymo The recommended way is `int[][][] x`

Comment: Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 4):

It is legal because [Java Language Specification - 10.2. Array Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2) allows it:

> The array type of a variable depends on the bracket pairs that may appear as part of the type at the beginning of a variable declaration, or as part of the declarator for the variable, or **both**.

(emphasis mine)

So to put it simply `int[] []x[];` is same as `int[][][] x;`.

---

Generally we should avoid mixed way of placing `[]` (or even placing `[]` after variable name). IMO it is because in Java we are used to declaring variables as

```
FullTypeDescription variableName
```

instead of

```
SomeTypeInfo variable RestOfTypeInformation
```

and number of arrays dimensions is part of type information, so it should be separated.

Mixed type is allowed to let us write code like (to let C or C++ programmers migrate to Java easier):

```
int[][] a, b[];
```

instead of

```
int[][] a;
int[][][] b;
```

but still last way is preferred.

Comment: A bit further down, the linked JLS says *"We do not recommend "mixed notation" in an array variable declaration, where brackets appear on both the type and in declarators"*, so they actually discourage the use of both `int[] []x[]` and `int[][] a, b[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Although the follow 3 mean the same, the first one is the recommended one, since the *type* of `x` is an array of integers.

```
int[] x;   // Recommended
int x[];
int []x;
```

So, the other one should be:

```
int[][][] x;
```

Which is an array of array of array of integers.

Depending on how it is used, it can be thought of as a 3-dimensional array, e.g. see [Fundamentals of Multidimensional Arrays](http://www.functionx.com/java/Lesson22.htm)

Of course, in reality, Java doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays. It is, as first stated, an array of array of array of integers, and each sub-array may have different lengths. But that is a longer topic.

Comment: why is it recommended? is there a reason to why programmers practice placing array brackets immediately after the variable?

Comment: See [JLS 10.2. Array Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2), where it says *"Brackets are allowed in declarators as a nod to the tradition of C and C++."*. As I said in answer, the `[]` makes the type an array, so putting it with the array base type (`int`) makes sense, e.g. `int[] x` is a variable `x` of type `int[]`. That JLS section also stated *"We do not recommend "mixed notation" in an array variable declaration, where brackets appear on both the type and in declarators"*, which is what OP did.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
int[][] array = new int[1][2];
```

Above we have a double-dimensional array. Really, it's an *array of arrays*. So declaring it like so:

```
int[] array[] = new int[1][2];
```

You are still declaring an array of arrays, aka a double-dimensional array. this means that this:

```
int[] []array[] = new int[1][2][3];
```

Is the same as this:

```
int[][][] array = new int[1][2][3];
```

Because brackets after the array identifier ('array') were adapted for C programmers, they are treated as though they're located before the identifier.

Hope this helps! :)